# CVS in cmd/gui works only the third time I run a command

Tags: linux, cvs, cmd, stunnel

I'm using CVS in the command line. I'm in my repository folder. When I call a CVS command, I get...

```
cvs [log aborted]: unrecognized auth response from localhost: -f [pserver
aborted]: /opt/cvs/XXXXXX: no such repository
```

...2 times. The third time I run the command, it works with no problems. I tried to use a GUI client (CrossVC) and the same problem occurs. I tried inside gVim and Vim using VCSCommand and I'm having the same issues as well.

I've tested with different times between each command, but I still have the same problems.

I'm using a CVS configuration with stunnel. Why am I having problem with this setup? Why every time just the **third** time that I try to run the command that actually works? Can this be a concurrency bug or something in stunnel?

Each test took different time pauses between each call: sometimes it was 10s, 1 minute, and everytime, just the third time it worked.

Comment: I have seen something similar with wget.  Never figured that one out.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Third time is the charm! You never know with cvs.

Comment: I know CVS is crap, but I can't change it since I'm not responsible for these configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in my stunnel.conf.

There are 3 ports definitions to 3 different machines, and it called two wrong machines before the right one (even if the correct one is above all the other in the file normal sequence).

I still don't have a complete solution to this problem, but the workaround is to comment all servers instead of the one you exactly need.